# Railscasts196, Rails 4, simple_form, JS, haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railscasts

As in Railscasts196, I have nested `Attendances` in `Events`, `Events` in `Event_groups`:

```
= simple_form_for(@event_group) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
  .h2 Events (not simple form)
  = f.fields_for :events do |p|
  = link_to_add_fields "Add field", p, :fields
    .field
      = p.label :starts_at
      = p.hidden_field :_destroy
      = link_to "[remove]", '#', class: "remove_fields"
        %p
        = p.fields_for :attendances do |f|
          .field
            = f.label :guest_id
            = f.text_field :guest_id
            = f.label :attendance_rate_id
            = f.text_field :attendance_rate_id
```

Event_groups.js:

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .remove_fields', (event) ->
  $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
  $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
  event.preventDefault()

$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

Application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

Now I can't make the jQuery work as in Railscasts for `Delete` and `Add new`. Something must be wrong with the `link_to_add_fields` & `remove`. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, nowadays there's a better way, using the [**cocoon** gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

It's very simple and I've had great success using it ;) hope you do too!

Comment: I will have a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have created a repo about nesting model forms from rails cast episode 196/197 compatible with rails 5. It works just fine [nesting-models-form](https://github.com/Mtali/multiple-model-nesting)